# How to continuously increase a value with the mouse?

Tags: interface

I have an issue when I want to increase / decrease values on controls like these:

[image: increase and decrease arrows in Blender controls]

Clicking the arrow will only increase/decrease a notch. I'd like to see the value change as long as I keep the click down.

How do I change this behaviour ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hover over the field, hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and scroll with the mouse wheel or drag these as you would a slider.